# Using IF Statement In mySQL

Tags: mysql, if-statement

i try to use IF statement in Mysql but failed to get result as i want. Below is my code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc()
BEGIN
DECLARE netname  varchar(100);
DECLARE alarm varchar(100);
SET netname = (SELECT `netname ` FROM summary_alarm);
SET alarm = (SELECT `alarm` FROM summary_alarm);
    IF ( netname = 'Abcd' AND alarm = 'Example Name') THEN
        BEGIN
        update summary_alarm set `count`=`count`+1;
        END
    END IF
END 
DELIMITER ;
```

What i want to achieve is update the record if it having 'Abcd' on column `netname` and having 'Example Name' on column `alarm`.
Any adea?

Comment: The table `summary_alarm` has only one single row?

Comment: Then your SET statements wont work.  They will return many rows - how does MySql know which row from summary_alarm to use?

Comment: i thought using "IF ( netname = 'Abcd' AND alarm = 'Example Name')" will help me pointing which row i want to update. Then im wrong?how to make it works?

Answer (score 0):

Something that doesn't look right is:

```
SET netname = (SELECT `netname ` FROM summary_alarm);
SET alarm = (SELECT `alarm` FROM summary_alarm);
```

I think you need to add a `WHERE` clause or a `GROUP BY` or a `LIMIT 1` to the `SELECT` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the newest comment, the `UPDATE` statement can be updated itself. Like so

```
UPDATE summary_alarm 
SET `count`=`count`+1
WHERE `netname` = 'Abcd' 
    AND `alarm` = 'Example Name';
```

Comment: Thanks Dream Eater, but i just want to know how to use IF statement  here.

Comment: You can not use the `IF` statement in such cases, which is why the `UPDATE` syntax supports `WHERE` clause.